# Processing constructor and function errors

Tags: function, constructor, processing

I am working with processing and i am getting the following errors in my code. If anyone can help me i would really apperciate it.

I am getting the following errors:

1. The constructor does not exist I have the constructor on top.
2. The function `getRowName(int)` does not exist.

Could you please help me get through this hurdle?

Thank you [code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1roU2.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, because they're hard to read, and we can't copy and paste them. Instead, please post a [mcve] directly in your question.

Comment: Also, please add the tag of your language (java?) to your question.